# Why does `scripting.executeScript` in Safari return a `null` element array instead of `InjectionResult` element array?

Tags: safari, webkit, browser-extension, safari-web-extension

I've recently noticed a strange behaviour in Safari when injecting a content script with `scripting.executeScript`.

The expectation here is that an array of `InjectionResult` objects will be returned (one for each frame the script was executed in). In all other browsers our extension supports (Chrome, Firefox*, Edge, Brave and Opera) this is indeed the behaviour I've observed.

Safari however, at least on both 15 and 16 that I've been able to test, returns an array containing a `null` element. I have confirmed that the scripts execute as expected without error, but even if they did error the expectation would be to have the `error` field of an `InjectionResult` object populated.

Below are two simple scripts I used to confirm this across all of the mentioned browsers. I made sure to test using both a script expecting arguments and one without, just in case that was somehow the cause. I also tried both a `void` return and returning a primitive value from the scripts.

###### Manifest Version 3

```js
const foo = await browser.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId },
    func: () => {
        console.log('Hello, from an injected script! o/');
    },
});
console.log({ foo });

const bar = await browser.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId },
    args: [1337],
    func: (param: number) => {
        console.log(`Hello, from an injected script! o/ With '${param}' argument!`);
        return param;
    },
});
console.log({ bar });
```

###### *Manifest Version 2 (for Firefox)

```js
const foo = await browser.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
    code: 'console.log("Hello, from an injected script! o/")',
});
console.log({ foo });

const param = 1337;
const bar = await browser.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
    code: `console.log('Hello, from an injected script! o/ With "${param}" argument!'); ${param};`,
});
console.log({ bar });
```

The outputs for the `console.log` statements above are as follows :-

###### Chrome | Brave | Edge | Opera

```js
foo: [{documentId: '...', frameId: 0, result: null}]
bar: [{documentId: '...', frameId: 0, result: 1337}]
```

###### *Firefox

```js
foo: [undefined]
bar: [1337]
```

###### Safari

```js
foo: [null]
bar: [null]
```

Since Safari's output more closely resembles that of Firefox under MV2, it feels like Safari supports MV3 but is still kind of stuck in this weird limbo between MV2.

###### Desperate attempt snippet

The observation of the above MV3/MV2 limbo led me to try drop the `return` statement, and instead just have `param;` as the last evaluated statement. In line with how returns work under MV2 in Firefox as follows:-

```js
func: (param: number) => {
    console.log(`Hello, from an injected script! o/ With '${param}' argument!`);
    param;
},
```

This, thank goodness, didn't work.

This behaviour feels like it should almost surely be a bug in WebKit, or am I completely missing something?

Comment: Running into exactly the same issue here. Have you managed to work around this somehow?

Comment: Just found a workaround here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/714225
Apparently, using `files` instead of `func` seems to work... The results are still returned directly (instead of an `InjectionResult` object), but at least _something_ is returned...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I unfortunately cannot use `files` in our case. My workaround was to essentially have wrapper code that is included only when targeting Safari, that explicitly uses `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` to return the result. I hate it. But it at least enabled me to have this Safari-specific wrapper code exist in its own single place, leaving all the existing **sane** code untouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this was resolved, albeit undocumented, in a Safari 16.4.x release (either 16.4.0 or 16.4.1).

So to confirm, this now works across both `ISOLATED` and `MAIN` scripts:

```js
await browser.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: /* tab ID here */ },
    world: 'ISOLATED', // or 'MAIN'
    args: [1337],
    func: (param) => {
        console.log(`Hello, from an injected script! o/ With '${param}' argument!`);
        return param;
    },
});
```

Resulting in the following now:

###### Chrome | Brave | Edge | Opera

```js
[{documentId: '...', frameId: 0, result: 1337}]
```

##### Safari

```js
[1337]
```

The shape of the return is still unaligned with the other browsers, but I'll take that over `[null]` any day.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to `host_permissions` not being set for the site you are trying to run on. I can confirm that, after significant hair-pulling, I was able to get my results back, even when running with `world: "MAIN"` on Safari 16.4.1 (I had bugs that stopped it working in previous versions, though might still have actually worked with them too).

However, remember that [Safari doesn't return `InjectionResults`, it returns results directly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/scripting/executeScript#browser_compatibility). You should still be getting `bar: [1337]` though, so probably check your `host_permissions`.

Comment: Thanks for your input @AntonOfTheWoods. I was just on my way to update this question with an answer. It seems like this was an undocumented fix added sometime in 16.4.x (I'm assuming 16.4.1). I can confirm that prior to this, with all permissions in order, any return value was always received as `[null]`. But, even if the shape is still off, at least we get something now! So I can remove my gross workaround! \o/